# Is there a way to reflectively call a function in Objective-C from a string?

Tags: objective-c, reflection

Are there any Objective-C runtime functions that will allow me to get a function (or block) pointer from a string identifying the function? I need some way to dynamically find and invoke a function or static method based on some form of string identifying it.

Ideally this function should be able to exist in any dynamically loaded library.

Looking at [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), the best bet looks like `class_getClassMethod`, but there don't appear to be any function-related functions in this reference. Are there other raw C ways of getting a pointer to a function by name?

Comment: it is possible to get the function pointer from a symbol name, but it is (almost) not possible to call it without knowing the correct function type

Comment: @xlc Let's just assume I know the function's arguments for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to invoke some static objc method, you can make it as a class method of a class

```
@interface MyClas : NSObject
+ (int)doWork;
@end
```

and call the method by

```
[[MyClass class] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"doWork")];
```

if you real want to work with C-style function pointer, you can check [dlsym()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlsym.3.html)

> dlsym() returns the address of the code or data location specified by
>   the null-terminated character
>        string symbol.  Which libraries and bundles are searched depends on the handle 
>   parameter If dlsym() is called with the special handle RTLD_DEFAULT,
>   then all mach-o images in the process
>        (except those loaded with dlopen(xxx, RTLD_LOCAL)) are searched in the order they were loaded.  This
>        can be a costly search and should be avoided.

so you can use it to find the function pointer base on asymbol name

not sure why you want to do this, sometimes use function table can do

```
typedef struct {
    char *name,
    void *fptr // function pointer
} FuncEntry;

FuncEntry table[] = {
    {"method", method},
    {"method2", method2},
}

// search the table and compare the name to locate function, you get the idea
```

Comment: I'd recommend against the `dlsym` route;  fragile and rife with potential security holes.  Better solution;  define a class that has all possible dynamic entry points as methods.  Then *only* support invocation of the methods defined on that class.  This limits the bug/attack surface area significantly.

Answer (score 1):

If you know method signature you can create selector to it with `NSSelectorFromString` function, e.g.:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"doWork");
[worker performSelector:selector];
```

Comment: That assumes I have an instance I want to invoke the method on, but I just want a raw C-style function, not a method. A class method might be an alternative.

Comment: Wrap your raw functions into static methods of a class, then call them.

Comment: @moonwave99 That's what I'll do if I have to, but plain ole functions would be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do what you want with [libffi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libffi). But unless you are doing something like create your own scripting language or something like that where you need to do this sort of thing a lot. It is probable overkill

Comment: That looks very cool, but you're probably right that it's overkill if there's a lighter-weight way to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered the SAME thing.. and I guess, after having researched it a bit.. there is NOT a "standard C" way to do such a thing.. (gasp).. but to the rescue?  Objective C blocks!

An anonymous function.. that can be OUTSIDE any `@implementation`, etc...

```
 void doCFunction() { printf("You called me by Name!"); }
```

Then, in your objective-C method… you can somehow "get" the name, and "call" the function...

```
NSDictionary *functionDict = @{ @"aName" : ^{ doCFunction(); } };
NSString *theName = @"aName";

((void (^)()) functionDict[theName] )();
```

Result: `You called me by Name!`

Loves it!   ⌘

Comment: That is very cool and all, but the problem is building that `functionDict`. I don't just magically have a mapping of string to function (or block) pointer, hence the true point of the question.

Comment: You said you'd know, or come up with the name.. " dynamically find and invoke a function or static method based on some form of string identifying it." It sounds more like you want to "scrape" the method signatures of anonymous functions… not call them by "name".

Comment: I want to be able to store the name of a function in a persisted data store and be able to load and resolve it at some point in the future.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what this does.  For example.. you can load an array of names and run their matching functions stored in the dictionary based on the name alone!